# Merge data from three tables

Tags: sql, merge, union, multiple-columns

I have three tables, tbA, tbB & tbC with 2 cols. I would like to merge the three tables and group them by mID and produce a formatted output like this...

**mID,mAreaA,mAreaB,mAreaC**

---

Structure of table
**tbA**

mID,mAreaA

---

Structure of table
**tbB**

mID,mAreaB

---

Structure of table
**tbC**

mID,mAreaC

---

The data I have is as follows

> Table tbA
>  1,1.83
>  2,3.65
>   4,9.30
>
> Table tbB 1,6.15
>  3,5.40
>
> Table tbC
>  1,0.55

---

**The output I need is something like this...**

> mID,mAreaA,mAreaB,mAreaC
>   1,1.83,6.15,0.55
>  2,3.65,0,0
>   3,0,5.40,0
>  4,9.30,0,0

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is have a source of all the IDs from each table, so you can `LEFT JOIN` against it. This will ensure every ID is accounted for, and that 'missing' `mId` from each table are represented in the output as a NULL mArea.

```
SELECT
    merged.id as mID,
    a.mAreaA,
    b.mAreaB,
    c.mAreaC
FROM 
   (SELECT mid as id FROM tba
   UNION
   SELECT mid as id FROM tbb
   UNION
   SELECT mid as id FROM tbc) merged
LEFT JOIN tbA a ON merged.id = a.mid
LEFT JOIN tbB b ON merged.id = b.mid
LEFT JOIN tbC c ON merged.id = c.mid
```

There are probably must nicer ways to do this, but you haven't explained what database product you're using, and the schema seems quite unorthodox. I'd be worried if you had to do something like this very often. Also, where a value isn't found for `mAreaX`, NULL will be shown in the return values. If you need it to be non-null, then `coalesce` to an empty string.